# how to check why a regular expression is not working?

Tags: java, regex

This regular expression is not finding any matches.  In other languages I run it in, it works great.  In online regular expression testers like rubular.com it works great.

In java, it does not work.

What is different about java regular expressions that they break things like this?

Why doesn't it work? Furthermore, how can I figure out in the future why they wont match?

sample data

```
<link>http://www.wunderground.com/US/MI/Milan.html</link>
<description><![CDATA[Temperature: 89.4&deg;F | Humidity: 62% | Pressure: 29.65in      (Steady) | Conditions: Clear | Wind Direction: NW | Wind Speed: 1.6mph<img     src="http://server.as5000.com/AS5000/adserver/image?ID=WUND-00070&C=0" width="0" height="0"     border="0"/>]]>
</description>
```

and the code

```
protected void parseTemperature()
{

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/Temperature: ([0-9.]+)&deg/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(this.xml);

    if (m.find())
    {
         this.temperature = Double.valueOf(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need to escape the dot? `[0-9\.]`

Comment: @Pablo: No, when the dot appears inside a character class, it just matches a dot.  That's true in every regex flavor I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `/` characters surrounding the regex.

`Pattern.compile` takes a raw expression, not wrapped in `/`s.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you do not want to put delimiters on the ends of your expression. Change it to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Temperature: ([0-9.]+)&deg");
```

(Forward slashes removed)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `/` characters. The regular expression engine in Java will try to match those.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '/' at the beginning and end of your pattern, and it works just fine for me.